# How to store values from loop to a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I am new to R and programming, I want to store values from loop to a data frame in R. I want `ker`, `cValues`, `accuracyValues` values to be stored a data frame from bellow code. I am not able to achieve this, Data Frame is only saving last value not all the values.

Can you please help me with this please.

```
# Define a vector which has different kernel methods
kerna <- c("rbfdot","polydot","vanilladot","tanhdot","laplacedot",
           "besseldot","anovadot","splinedot")

# Define a for loop to calculate accuracy for different values of C and kernel
for (ker in kerna){
    cValues <- c()
    accuracyValues <- c()
    for (c in 1:100) {
        model <- ksvm(V11~V1+V2+V3+V4+V5+V6+V7+V8+V9+V10,
                      data = credit_card_data,
                      type ="C-svc",
                      kernel = ker,
                      C=c,
                      scaled =TRUE)
        pred <- predict(model,credit_card_data[,1:10])
        #pred
        accuracy <- sum(pred== credit_card_data$V11)/nrow(credit_card_data)

        cValues[c] <- c;
        accuracyValues[c] <- accuracy;

    }

    for(i in 1:100) {
        print(paste("kernal:",ker, "c=",cValues[i],"accuracy=",accuracyValues[i]))


    }

}
```

Comment: outside your loop, define another variable that will store all the results. for example a list.  Then store the values on the outer loop and not the inner loop

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your base code, set up the structure of the output data frame. Then, loop through and fill in the accuracy values on each iteration. This method also "flattens" the nested loop and gets rid of your `c` variable which conflicts with the built-in `c()` function.

```
kerna <- c("rbfdot","polydot","vanilladot","tanhdot","laplacedot",
           "besseldot","anovadot","splinedot")

# Create dataframe to store output data
df <- data.frame(kerna = rep(kerna, each = 100), 
                 cValues = rep(1:100, times = length(kerna)),
                 accuracyValues = NA,
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

# Define a for loop to calculate accuracy for different values of C and kernel
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  ker <- df$kerna[i]
  j <- df$cValues[i]
  model <- ksvm(V11~V1+V2+V3+V4+V5+V6+V7+V8+V9+V10,
                data = credit_card_data,
                type ="C-svc",
                kernel = ker,
                C=j,
                scaled =TRUE)
  pred <- predict(model,credit_card_data[,1:10])
  accuracy <- sum(pred== credit_card_data$V11)/nrow(credit_card_data)

  # Insert accuracy into df$accuracyValues
  df$accuracyValues[i] <- accuracy;
}
```

Comment: Consider `expand.grid`: `df <- expand.grid(kerna=kerna, cValues=1:100, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: Agreed, `expand.grid` is another great way of expanding the `kerna`, `cValue` pairs. Probably just comes down to preference - `rep` nicely illustrates what is being done behind the scenes but `expand.grid` is a more flexible option. Either way, pre-allocating the output data.frame will be more performant than generating a list of dataframes and merging later

Answer (score 0):

Consider `Map` to build a list of data frames from each pairing of *ker* and *cValues* (`1:100`) generated from `expand.grid` and row bind all elements together.

```
k_c_pairs_df <- expand.grid(kerna=kerna, c_value=1:100, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

model_fct <- function(ker, c) {
      model <- ksvm(V11~V1+V2+V3+V4+V5+V6+V7+V8+V9+V10,
                    data = credit_card_data,
                    type ="C-svc",
                    kernel = ker,
                    C=c,
                    scaled =TRUE)

      pred <- predict(model,credit_card_data[,1:10])
      accuracy <- sum(pred== credit_card_data$V11)/nrow(credit_card_data)

      print(paste("kernal:",ker, "c=",cValues[i],"accuracy=",accuracyValues[i]))

      return(data.frame(kernel = ker, cValues = c, accuracyValues = accuracy))
}

df_list <- Map(model_fct, k_c_pairs_df$ker, k_c_pairs_df$c_value)

final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```